# How to enhance this code (LINQ to Entity)

Tags: entity-framework

I have a form with gridview, when selecting a record from the GV it calls another page details.aspx, details page has a form with FormView using SelectMethod="GetData", to display the data for the selected id record, a follow:

```
Public Function GetData( ByVal id? As Integer) As Ems_Candidate
            Try
                // store record id in memVar to use it when retreve the image
                strRecNo = id.ToString

                Call LoadCandidateImage()

                Return _db.DbSet_Candidates.Find(id)

            Catch ex As Exception
                ModelState.AddModelError("ModelError", ex.Message.ToString)
                Return 1
            End Try
End Function
```

In the same time where the data binded to the FormView I had to display some data in a label from this record but outside the FormView model, I had update the above method to the following:

```
Public Function GetData( ByVal id? As Integer) As Ems_Candidate
        Try
            // store record id in memVar to use it when retrieve the image
            strRecNo = id.ToString

            Call LoadCandidateImage()

    // Start: new lines added
            Dim objQuery As IQueryable(Of Ems_Candidate) = _
                From c In _db.DbSet_Candidates
                Where c.CandidateID = id
                Select c

            For Each c In objQuery
                If c.CandidateStatus.Equals("A") Then
                    Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "Active"
                ElseIf c.CandidateStatus.Equals("D") Then
                    Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "Deleted"
                ElseIf c.CandidateStatus.Equals("W") Then
                    Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "Waived"
                Else
                    Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "N/A"
                End If
            Next

    // End: new lines added

            Return _db.DbSet_Candidates.Find(id)

        Catch ex As Exception
            ModelState.AddModelError("ModelError", ex.Message.ToString)
            Return 1
        End Try
End Function
```

I had to query the database again as IQueryable to be able to select the required data before I Return the data.

I don't thinkg this way is practical to hit the database twice in the same place, even I wouldn't do this if I'm using Ado.Net, is there a way to enhance the code?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the result of the query into a temporary variable, like this

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal id? As Integer) As Ems_Candidate
    Try
        // store record id in memVar to use it when retreve the image
        strRecNo = id.ToString

        Call LoadCandidateImage()

        Dim result As Ems_Candidate
        result = _db.DbSet_Candidates.Find(id)

        Select Case result.CandidateStatus
            Case "A"
                Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "Active"
            Case "D"
                Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "Deleted"
            Case "W"
                Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "Waived"
            Case Else
                Me.lblCandidateStatus.Text = "N/A"
        End Select

        Return result

    Catch ex As Exception
        ModelState.AddModelError("ModelError", ex.Message.ToString)
        Return 1
    End Try
End Function
```